# NLog in which folder it maintain log files

Tags: .net-core, nlog

log to save system logs in .netCore 2.0 it working properly when we deployed the build at IIS and at deployed directory creates a new folder with SystemLog and placing log files there.

And In deployment/debug mode it does not working no SystemLog folder.

1. Is I am missing anything related to debug configuration?
2. Is it only works in deployed mode?
3. which type of log is captured when minlevel is debug ,error,info

Below here I Placing my nlog.config file which is working in one case but not in other one

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>

<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <targets async="true">
    <!-- File to be Written  -->
    <!--<target xsi:type="File" name="otherFile-web" fileName="${FindAvailableDrive:Drives=C}/Logs/Log-${shortdate}.txt"/>-->
    <target  xsi:type="File" name="SystemLog" fileName="SystemLog\Log-${shortdate}.txt"/>

  </targets >
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="SystemLog" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Comment: Hi, please check https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting

Answer (score 0):

Currently, I am using this code and it's working fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  autoReload="true" internalLogLevel="Trace">
  <targets>
    <target
      name="logfile"
      xsi:type="File"
      fileName="../../../Logs/${shortdate}/${shortdate}_Logs.txt"
      layout="${longdate} | ${level:uppercase=true} | ${stacktrace:format=Raw} | ${message} ${newline}">
    </target>

    <target
      name="logconsole"
      xsi:type="Console">
    </target>

  </targets>
  <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="logconsole" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

1. It depends on you what type of log you want to write and where.
2. No
3. https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/Configuration-file#rules